# PHP - password_hash() Doesn't return anything after using ROT13

Tags: php, php-password-hash, rot13

In my php file I have 3 variables, one that includes the clear password and one that includes the clear password after reversed from the ROT13 encryption and my last variable that contains the hashed password.

```
 <?php
 $clearpwd = $_POST['var1']; //the password. note that this is not present here just doing this to compare values for the time until the error is solved (lets say that here the value is **something** for example)
 $reversedpwd = str_rot13($_POST['var2']); //reversedpwd holds the password given by another site that encrypted previously the password in ROT13
 $hashedpwd = '$2y$10$4sIma.5gA9sqoXckMG.Fru/hRxvV6nrodiI/24wvu.qp1jpLG1gU2';
 //a hash given by password_hash(something, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); note that the hash is already generated and not regenerated each time you execute the php so it's static. 
 
 echo password_verify($clearpwd, $hashedpwd); //returns 1
 echo password_verify($reversedpwd, $hashedpwd); //returns nothing
 ?>
```

So when i execute password_verify at the end both clearpwd and reversedpwd holds the exact same text ('something' in this example) but only with clearpwd i get 1.

Any idea or why it doesn't like to match the algorithm a text that was previously rot13 coded and then decoded to have the original string ('something') ??

Other info:
I'm using php ver 7.4 with Softaculous AMPPS.
The rot13 coded variable comes from an input that has been encrypted with rot13 with a php function, before it got sent over to this other php file to interpret it and verify it.

[image: output]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `var_dump($clearpwd, $reversedpwd, hashedpwd);` placed before your `password_verify()` calls.

Comment: Or just stop using ROT13 at all. What's the point of all this?

Comment: @Progman Indeed you were right. there is a missmatch after reconverting the rot13 encrypted value. Altough if there is only a whitespace why is it longer by 2 and not just 1 ?

Comment: @Fetert Check with `var_dump($_POST);` (or `var_dump($_POST['var1'], $_POST['var2']);`) what values you are receiving. If they are already wrong and not as expected as they should be, check the sender code.

Comment: @Progman the following `var_dump($_POST['var1'], $_POST['var2']);` gives this : `string(21) "D3Cxy4ra*saT43D@ds34s" string(23) "Q3Pkl4en*fnG43Q@qf34f "`  Basically the whitespace is the one thing that messes up the value as we can see there is a whitespace at the end of the encryped value

Comment: @Fetert Then the client is sending the data as that. Check the client source code you have.

Comment: @Progman Thank you i resolved it with the help of Ron van der Heijden who suggested to use trim on the variable after decryption. now the 2 variables are matching.

Comment: @Progman In my client code the function that calls for the encryption is made that way so I wouldn't be able to change anything there either way. (The function was premade not by me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$clearpwd` and `$reversedpwd` are not the same.

Try comparing them with `var_dump($clearpwd === $reversedpwd)`.

Perhaps there are some spaces around the text in the strings? Try `trim($reversedpwd)`.

Comment: Thank you! After using trim on the decrypted value now it matches the lenght of the first value.